# The derivative of $f(t, y(t))$ with respect to $t$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given a function $f(t, y(t))$, how can I express its derivative with respect to $t$ and $d f/{d t}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x = x(s,t)$, and $y = y(s,t)$, the chain rule for two variables is

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial s} f\big(x(s,t),y(s,t)\big) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\\
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f\big(x(s,t),y(s,t)\big) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
\end{align}

What happens if $x(s,t) = t$ and $y(s,t) = y(t)$?

Comment: @F'OlaYinka Really? Any multivariable calculus textbook will have the construction. A good introductory textbook is Marsden and Tromba's _Vector Calculus_.